# How can I make a <p> element display on the hover of its parent <div> using CSS?

Tags: css

```
.divtwochild {
    font-size: 24pt;
    margin-left: 500px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 400px;
    display: inline-block;}

.divtwochild:hover, .divtwochild {
    display: block;}

.divtwotext {
    font-size: 30pt;
    font-family: open sans;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: right;
    display: none;}
```

the html is simply a `<p>` element in a `<div>` element. Want to display the `<p>` element when the parent `<div>` is hovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select it based off the hover condition of the parent, as such

```
.parent {
    /* Whatever */
}
.child {
    /* Whatever */
    display:none;
}
.parent:hover .child {
    /* Whatever */
    display: initial;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g6ur51xj/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean?

```
<div id="parent">
    <p>Hover me</p>
    <div class="child">
        <p>u hovered over the hover me</p>
    </div>
</div>

#parent:hover > .child{
    visibility:visible;
}
.child{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

That will display the html inside the child div

Here is a working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/4h1y818t/)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this is more or less what you're after:

```css
div.show-content-on-hover p {
  display: none;
}
div.show-content-on-hover:hover p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="show-content-on-hover">
  <h3>Hover here to see an awesome quote:</h3>
  <p>
    <q>As Gregor Samsa awoke one morning from uneasy dreams he found himself transformed in his bed into a gigantic insect.</q>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use something like this:

```
.p-child {display:none;}
.parent-div {height:50px; width:300px;}
.parent-div:hover > .p-child {display:block;}
```

You will want to be sure to set your parent div to a specific height and width because if it's only content is set to display:none the parent div will collapse by default.

Another alternative is to use:

```
.p-child {opacity:0;}
.parent-div:hover > .p-child {opacity:1;}
```

Which allows the font to set the dimensions of the parent div.